# "Uncaught Exception" in Scala application log

Tags: scala, exception, actor

In the log of my `Scala` server I noticed a few errors:

```
Exit. Uncaught exception. Message = ..., Sender = ...
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
...
```

I guess `Scala` prints out this error if an exception occurs in some actor code, the actor does not catch the exception and exits. Is it correct?

What does exactly happen here? Does `Scala` actors library add its own library exception handler to catch uncaught exceptions and print this message?